# How to show two different view in Listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have main activity which contain a listview when I scroll down it send request to server and fetch more items in listview and if there is no more items on server server send "no item" in response on that response I have to add one more View as footer or something else that view contain one more listview with some items.How can I do that.

code for adapter:-

```
    private final Context m_Context;// declaring context variable
    private final ArrayList<CDealAppDatastorage> s_oDataset;// declaring array list ariable

    public CDealAppListingAdapter(Context m_Context, ArrayList<CDealAppDatastorage> mDataList) {
        this.m_Context = m_Context;
        s_oDataset = mDataList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {// get total arraylist size
        return s_oDataset.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {// get item position in array list
        return s_oDataset.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "InflateParams"})
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deallisting_card_view, null);
            viewHolder.m_Header = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headingText);
            viewHolder.m_Subheader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subHeaderText);
            viewHolder.m_DummyText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subHeadingText);
            viewHolder.m_logoImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appImage);
            viewHolder.m_getBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.getDealBtn);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.m_getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {// onclick getDeal Btn
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {//send to deal detail page onclick getDeal Btn
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), CDealAppListingDetails.class);
                i.putExtra("DealCode", s_oDataset.get(position).getM_szsubHeaderText());// get deal code from deal data storage
                i.putExtra("headerText", s_oDataset.get(position).getM_szHeaderText());// get deal name from deal dta storage
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        CDealAppDatastorage m = s_oDataset.get(position);
        viewHolder.m_Header.setText(m.getM_szHeaderText());
        viewHolder.m_Subheader.setText(m.getM_szsubHeaderText());
        viewHolder.m_getBtn.setText("GET " + m.getM_szDealValue() + " POINTS");// set deal button text
        viewHolder.m_logoImage.setImageResource(m.getM_n_Image());// set deal logo

        String source = "Dummy text is text that is used in the publishing industry or by web designers to occupy space.";
        viewHolder.m_DummyText.setText(Html.fromHtml(source));



        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView m_Header, m_Subheader, m_DummyText;
        public ImageView m_logoImage;
        public Button m_getBtn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here You have code for inflating view ( in getView method ):

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deallisting_card_view, null);
```

just add some if statement and inflate different views for different elements

```
if (someExpression)
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view1, null);
else
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view2, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the method getViewType in Adapter, then get the type in getView(), inflate the views you want .

```
switch(getViewType()){

   case value:

     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deallisting_card_view, parent,false);

   break;

   case value:

   break; 
}
```

by the way , when you inflate a item , you'd better add the parent , do not make it as a null.

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deallisting_card_view, null);
```

change to

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deallisting_card_view, parent,false);
```

hope it would help